# How to select a single photo from an "Event" to drag it into the timeline?

Tags: imovie

I am struggling to use iMovie. I have created some "Events" and added a bunch of photos to each "Event". Now I want to drag single photos from that collection of photos to the actual timeline. But when I grab a single photo, it copies the whole content of the "Event" on the timeline.

So how can I select a single photo to drag that single photo to the timeline?

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Just select some photos together (Click and Shift-Click) which unselects the whole collection of photos in the "Event".

Then you also can select a single photo (not shown as "marked" anymore) and you can drag that single photo to the timeline.

Typical `iMovie`: The opposite of intuitive...

Comment: I can't figure out what wasn't intuitive. Whatever is highlighted in yellow is currently selected. If all are selected, just click somewhere in blank space to deselect all.